# Apple ethernet slower than Dell ethernet?

Tags: macbook-pro, windows, catalina, ethernet

Same Ethernet port, same USB C-Ethernet adapter, a Dell laptop (with Windows) vs. a 2017 MacBook Pro with Catalina. MacBook Pro gets around 45 Mbps download while the Dell laptop gets 1000 Mbps. Why?

I do have Symantec Endpoint Protection on the Mac if that helps.

Comment: I would certainly test without SEP. I can certainly get 1000Mbps Ethernet speeds on my Apple gear.

Comment: Not all USB-C Ethernet adapters are created equal. After experimentation, the [Belkin USB-C to Gigabit Ethernet Adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/HJKF2ZM/A/belkin-usb-c-to-gigabit-ethernet-adapter) works best on our Mac laptops. After years of needing various adapters, the Belkin brand seems to be the most rugged and compatible. _Note: no financial or other connection to Belkin, Inc._